# is it possible to change the value in a dropdown using Javascript when dropdown is disabled

Tags: javascript, c#, drop-down-menu

I have a web form where i disable a dropdown on page load in C#.

The drop down is to be disabled at all times, only when users make a certain selection is when I would like to change the value in my drop down. Either Yes or No.

This is my Javascript code:

```
    var drpModeNeed = document.getElementById("drpAssessID"); //This dropdown is 
               //where I'm looking to change the value (it is disabled)

    var drp4Val = (document.getElementById('<%=drp4ID.ClientID %>').value);
    var drp14Val = (document.getElementById('<%=drp14ID.ClientID %>').value);
    var drp15Val = (document.getElementById('<%=drp15ID.ClientID %>').value);

    if (drp4Val == 1 || (drp14Val == 1 && drp15Val == 1)) 
    {
        //trying to change the value here of dropdown
    }
```

This is what I've tried in the if statement

```
    drpModeNeed.options[drpModeNeed.selectedIndex].value == 1;
```

but nothing happens. I know for sure that it definitely recognizes the statements, becase I've placed an alert inside the IF statement and each time it would show that the values were definitely selected.

I guess I'm wondering if I'm able to change the value of a disabled dropdown? if I am, then why isn't the code working?

Comment: Do you want to change the currently-selected `<option>`, or do you want to change the `.value` property of one of the `<option>` elements? Your code is currently doing the latter.

Comment: @Pointy - i'm trying to have it select the "1" value. Basically if you look at the var drp4Val and var drp14Val - each of those dropdowns have the same value. In this case in the if statement, i'm checking if .value = 1 (YES), if so, then set the value in drpModeNeed to == 1 (YES). don't know if that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: What you need to do then is change the value of `drpModeNeed.selectedIndex` or else set the `selected` property of the target `<option>` to `true`.

Comment: @Pointy ....this seems to work -->drpModeNeed.options[1].selected = "selected"; If you would like to post as answer I'd accept it

Comment: You could also use `drpModeNeed.value = 2` where 2 is the value of the option you want selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the effective value of a `<select>` element, you don't set the `.value` of an `<option>`, you set the `.selected` property to `true` (or any truthy value):

```
drpModeNeed.options[1].selected = true;
```

Keep in mind that if the `<select>` element has the `.disabled` property set, posting the enclosing `<form>` will not send that value to the server. The browser assumes that disabled elements are supposed to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me:

```js
 function changeValue(newValue){
  var drpModeNeed = document.getElementById("drpAssessID");
  drpModeNeed.value=newValue;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<select id="drpAssessID" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="2">two</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="changeValue(1);">Set 1</button>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="changeValue(2);">Set 2</button>


</body>
</html>
```